# Republish project error with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, weblogic-10.x, hotdeploy

I have a problem with eclipse and my project. When I start the server (weblogic 10.3) and publish my project, all work fine.

But when I modify a class and republish the project (without restart the server), I get the following error:

```
   weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1373)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:468)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.AnnotationException
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:283)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:256)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:54)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
```

If I restart the server, it work.

My hibernate jar are in the project (WEB-INF/lib).

I don't understand this error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hot deployment (or fastswap as it's called in Weblogic) (redeploying your application without restarting the application server) is always a bit sticky. I haven't worked much with Weblogic, but for example JBoss supports hot deployment but discourages any reliance on it.

According to [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/deployment/deployunits.html#wp1054284) cite therd are a limited number of changes that a fastswap can handle. I think you're running into a similar problem.

I suspect that you simply need to get used to restarting your application server every once in a while.

Comment: I tried to republish without any change in my application and I get the same error. I lose many time to restart the server each time.